# cocos2d (iPhone/iPad) incorrectly scales -hd (retina) assets to 50% display size

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I've read the [cocos2d guide to retina displays](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d). I have both regular and `-hd` assets in my game. The problem is that the retina display devices look different than non-retina, as if the image had been scaled to 50%. Consider the following screenshot, with the iPhone (non-retina) on left, and iPhone 5 (retina) on the right:

[image]

Notice how on the right screenshot, the assets have been scaled down by 50% **despite the fact** that the `-hd` assets are @2x. For example, with the "leaf icon" there is `green_icon.png` (50x50 px) and `green_icon-hd.png` (100x100 px). In the left image, it is showing @ 50x50 px (correct), but in the right image it is showing at 25x25px (incorrectly scaling down the retina image, it seems).

Here's my startup code:

```
NSString *EXT_HD = @"-hd";
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:YES];
[sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:EXT_HD forKey:(NSString*)kCCFileUtilsiPhoneHD];
[sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:EXT_HD forKey:(NSString*)kCCFileUtilsiPhone5HD];
[sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:EXT_HD forKey:(NSString*)kCCFileUtilsiPadHD];
[sharedFileUtils.suffixesDict setValue:EXT_HD forKey:(NSString*)kCCFileUtilsMacHD];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
```

(Note that I have also tried explicitly disabling retina display with no luck).

Here's my actual implementation of creating a sprite (for example, the green leaf icon):

`[CCSprite spriteWithFile:fpIcon];`

Pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found out that this was happening because I was passing an absolute image asset path to cocos2d. For reasons I won't get into, this was necessary in my game. However, cocos2d intentionally does not attempt to use `-hd` (or other variants) on a file path when the absolute path is provided.

Specifically, you can see that `CCFileUtils.m` aborts from `fullPathForFilename` if it is passed a full path:

```
-(NSString*) fullPathForFilename:(NSString*)filename resolutionType:(ccResolutionType*)resolutionType
{
    // fullpath? return it
    if ([filename isAbsolutePath]) {
        CCLOGWARN(@"cocos2d: WARNING fullPathForFilename:resolutionType: should not be called with absolute path. Instead call fullPathForFilenameIgnoringResolutions:");
        *resolutionType = kCCResolutionUnknown;
        return filename;
    }
```